# Java WEB vs Java SE. Математические расчеты

Tags: java-ee, java

Всем привет!

Встал такой вопрос -  необходимо разработать сложную систему по расчету загрязнения,и сложность её заключается в том, что будет много математических расчетов.

Вопрос заключается: "на какой платформе разрабатывать"? И есть ли разница на какой платформе, если они используют одинаковые математические библиотеки?

Спасибо за внимание =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разницы нет никакой: J2EE=J2SE + enterprise библиотеки.

Советую больше внимания обратить на ось поверх которой работает JVM, на некоторых осях матфункции Java реализованы в нативном виде, а кое-где и в виде чистой Java.

Для Intel x86/64 матфункции реализованы в виде вызова нативных сишных функций, так что там все гуд. В свое время сталкивался с тем, что java.math был реализован на чистой Java для OS Solaris - не знаю может быть сейчас уже переделано.

Также имеет смысл обратить внимание на разрядность JVM - по идее для тяжелых матвычислений x64 должен подойти лучше, хотя не уверен.

Comment: А поверх Linux тоже все гуд?

Comment: Ну если Linux над Intel то все гуд. В любом случае не будет лишним посмотреть на исходники скажем `math.sin()/cos()`

Comment: А разве есть разница, как и что написано в джаве, JIT же заменяет почти всю Math.* на интринсики?

Comment: JIT заменит на нативный, если он (нативный код) есть в наличии. Скажем для x86/x64 с матсопроцессором он заменит на инструкции мат.сопроцессора, а если нет - значит нет.

Comment: Ну так в вашем примере получается нет разницы между pure java implementation и вызовом native функций. В обоих случаях эти реализации задействованы в JIT коде не будут. Интерпретатор тоже умеет вызывать Math интринсики. Ну и сейчас редко используется сопроцессор, обычно код float-point арифметики юзает SSE.

Answer (score 3):

Принципиальных различий в производительности между Java SE и Java EE нет. Java EE - это та же Java, не с кучей дополнительных библиотек, заточенных под веб-разработку. Виртуальная машина, исполняющая программы что для SE, что для EE одна.

Достаточно странным выглядит выбор именно Java для реализации сложных математических расчётов. Если они действительно такие тяжёлые, может стоит их реализовать на C, возможно, с переносом вычислений на GPU? Если так хочется использовать Java, на ней можно написать фронтенд для вычислительной части, написанной на C.

Comment: А большие расхождения по времени выполнения(не завалялась ли где ссылочка на сравнительный анализ скорости вычисления Java и С)?

P.S.
Ну если такая пьянка, то можно и на assembler'е написать )

Comment: Вот ряд бенчмарков нескольких языков программирования: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/ Как раз тяжёлые математические расчёты.